# Java do while loop not looping

Tags: java, loops, do-loops

I'm having a bit of trouble with this do while loop. The system will print out the line and stop. What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your time!

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String answer;
    int inputNum = 1;
    int countOdd = 0;
    int countEven = 0;

    do{
        do{
            System.out.println("Please enter an interger. When you are finished, enter 0.");
            inputNum = keyboard.nextInt();

                while (inputNum % 2 == 0)
                    countOdd++;
                while (inputNum % 2 != 0)
                    countEven++;
        }while(inputNum != 0);


        System.out.println("Thank you. The amount of odd intergers you entered is " 
        + countOdd + ". The amount of even intergers you entered is " + countEven);


        System.out.println("Thank you. The amount of odd intergers you entered is " 
        + countOdd + ". The amount of even intergers you entered is " + countEven);

        System.out.println("Would you like to run this program again? (Y) (N)");
        answer = keyboard.nextLine();

    }while (answer.equals("Y"));

    System.out.println("Thank you!");
}
```

}

Comment: Do you ever close the outer `{`?

Comment: Never heard of a do loop, only a do while loop. Where's the while?

Comment: `"The system will print out the line and stop"` So what is it printing and what is your expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)

Comment: ... After seeing @BalwinderSingh's answer, I see `nextLine` isn't the problem. (But it will be your next problem after you fix the while/if problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following loops cannot be finished, since `inputNum` is not changed inside:

```
          while (inputNum % 2 == 0)
                countOdd++;
          while (inputNum % 2 != 0)
                countEven++;
```

You need `if` statements here instead of `while`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `while` with `if`. The logic `inputNum%2==0` checks for even not odd.But if you did it intentionally opposite ,its fine. I changed it as it should be.

```
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String answer;
    int inputNum = 1;
    int countOdd = 0;
    int countEven = 0;


        do{
            System.out.println("Please enter an interger. When you are finished, enter 0.");
            inputNum = keyboard.nextInt();

             if (inputNum % 2 == 0)
                 countEven++;
               if (inputNum % 2 != 0)
                   countOdd++;
        }while(inputNum != 0);


        System.out.println("Thank you. The amount of odd intergers you entered is " 
        + countOdd + ". The amount of even intergers you entered is " + countEven);
```

Comment: Why down voting?? its 100% correct answer. Plus the logic is also corrected.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the following lines of code

```
while (inputNum % 2 == 0)
                countOdd++;
while (inputNum % 2 != 0)
                countEven++;
```

You don't use `while` statements for `if` conditions. Instead use this

```
 if (inputNum % 2 == 0)
                    countOdd++;
 if (inputNum % 2 != 0)
                    countEven++;
```